# seeking recommendations for simple in-memory DB *server* (no persistence needed)

Tags: c++, database, linux, odbc, in-memory-database

Should support multiple connections, preferably via ODBC. The clients will be running as separate processes on the same machine. No need for persistence, as the the clients will handle the persistence elsewhere. The clients are written in C++ if it matters.

The data is quite simple, it is a set of unrelated bi-directional maps. The access is either directly by a value or by a range (`between X and Y`), no updates. We don't actually need SQL here, so non-SQL solutions can also be considered.

The client application is multi-process and can run on several machines. Each machine should have a local copy of such DB, which is updated against the central store by its local clients.

**Multiple Edits**:

1. the platform is Linux
2. RAM disk is not an option for security reasons - we don't want that anyone with access to the machine would be able to view the data
3. the data should may be persisted only in encrypted form, so the solution should either not persist the data at all or allow a user-defined filter/plugin for persistence.

Comment: Berkeley DB supports in-memory databases as well as replication. You can also run anything (including RDBMS/SQL servers) on "in-memory" file systems.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: I usually don't ask question without researching and analyzing the issue first. "in-memory file systems" (aka RAM disk) was considered and found not applicable for security reasons. I believe that downvoting (if it's you) is not deserved.

Comment: @davka: It could have been helpful if you specified this in your question as well. I don't downvote questions though.

Comment: @Vlad: I agree. We considered quite a few design alternatives, so I forgot...

Comment: If you have a security problem with RAM disks and chmoding the working dir to 700 then you seriously need to rethink your architecture. There is zilch-all from stopping root from periodically dumping /proc/PID/mem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because of my familiarity with it, I would go with mysql.  To use it as an in memory database use memory as the table type.  Redis is an in memory NoSql Database that would probably be a perfect fit for this(It runs in memory, with disc writing for persistence only which can be disabled).

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. Do you know if Radis supports ranges, or at least `get next/previous key` commands? 
Another issue is that we actually **should not** have persistent data in non-encrypted form. Should have mentioned this in the question...

Comment: Yes, Redis does range queries.

Comment: speaking of mysql, do you have a rough idea how much a per-client installation license could cost?

Comment: To tell you the truth I have never really understood Oracle's licensing scheme.  To me Mysql appears to be free for use, pay for support or access to value adds like monitoring tools.

Comment: selecting this answer as it was useful to learn about Redis, although not yet sure it is suitable for us

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason for not using SQLite with a RAM db opened?

Comment: yes - we need a **server** as opposed to the embedded in-proc DB. We are trying to avoid developing server layer for sqlite. See my other comments below

Answer (score 1):

> RAM disk is not an option for security reasons - we don't want that anyone with access to the machine would be able to view the data

You're out of luck. Anyone with access to the machine can view the data out of /proc/$PID/mem anyway.

If you're talking nonroot access than use the /tmp/$directory/ method with chmod 700.

Comment: perhaps, but I assume that figuring out the data structure of an im-memory DB is much harder than copying a db file from a RAM disk to a DVD and taking it home...

Comment: Without knowing your specific case, about 80% of the time strings will get you enough to do serious damage.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "time strings", but anyway - the current requirement is to be protected from *physical* stealing of the db file(s). This is a regulatory issue. I agree that serious hacking into the process's memory using root privileges can reveal the data, but it seams much harder. I am trying to get the requirement better spcified

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick you can use under Linux, it is called "Lazy unmount".

1. Mount a tmpfs somewhere
2. Start up some process(es) to use it, which chdir() into that directory. You can use a mysql instance; mysql always does a chdir to its data directory.
3. After the process has started up successfully, umount the tmpfs with the -l (lazy) option.

Now the tmpfs still exists and will continue to exist as long as process(es) are accessing it, but it cannot be accessed by unrelated processes any more as it is no longer present in its mount-point.

Note that this in no way stops root from obtaining the data in the tmpfs, just makes it a little harder.

Also note that it may be swapped, so you should disable swap (or use encrypted swap) if you absolutely need it to be non-persistent.

Comment: /proc/$PID/fd/* will not allow you to access the files in the tmpfs; the symlinks won't be valid. I've tried it.

Comment: Works for me if you actually descend through them rather than readlink.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).  Not an obvious choice but it's based on relational DB concepts.

> The concept of multi-indexing over the
>   same collection of elements is
>   borrowed from relational database
>   terminology and allows for the
>   specification of complex data
>   structures in the spirit of multiply
>   indexed relational tables where simple
>   sets and maps are not enough. A wide
>   selection of indices is provided,
>   modeled after analogous STL containers
>   like std::set, std::list and hashed
>   sets.

Comment: I've used this with memory mapped files. Can't handle transactions so a change of getting corrupted data is very high. It also doesn't support replication. But it is a nice solution for certain problems though!

Comment: @Vlad - thanks for the info.  Had not had much to do with this library but answered a couple of qs in this area recently, and it looks very useful.

Comment: I am familiar with it, but it is `in-process` container. Our application is multi-process so we don't want to replicate the data in each process. Even more so as some of the processes run per request, so we will need to initialize the container each time. Hence the need for *server*, one per machine.

Comment: @davka - in-memory DBs are typically per-process, not per machine.  You will probably have to write a process to host any in-memory DB (or cache) you come up with, and provide a proxy to that process to support multiple clients per machine that needs to access persisted data hosted in the backend DB.

Comment: @Steve: This exactly is what we are trying to avoid, at least in the first phase... :) Otherwise, the choice of embedded in-memory db seems quite simpler, starting with sqlite

Comment: If you plan to allow each process to have a separate in-memory cache I don't see the value of this versus going direct to the DB and letting it cache what's needed.  The processes will all hit the DB separately in loading up the required data - is that really what you want?  Footprint on the client machines could be a problem here too.  Keeping clients up-to-date wrt writes elsewhere is also more complex with this design.

Comment: @Steve: agreed completely. We don't want each process to have a separate cache, that's why I'm looking for a server. We also hope to avoid writing a "private" server wrapper for an embedded in-memory DB, at least initially.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql with datadir= a tmpfs you've mounted for the purpose. You'll need to cook up some startup script which installs the database (using mysql_install_db or something) at boot-time, of course, as you'll lose all the data.

Comment: thanks but please see my recent edits - ramdisk/tmpfs was considered and rejected for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

[memcached](http://memcached.org/) can be a viable solution. It is a key-value store that can be set to hold values for a certain amount of time, is scalable and is simple to set up and start using. It is also run in all sorts of environments. [Here's the wiki site for more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached), especially since the main page isn't nearly has helpful.

Comment: laconic, but I'll look at it again. Do you know if it supports ranges, e.g. `get next/previous key`?

Comment: seems not, from what I can figure out from the command list