# looking for a stand-alone, in-memory data server with sequential access

Tags: c++, database, linux, nosql, in-memory-database

We need an in-memory data structure / DB **server** with following characteristics:

1. *stand-alone server*: will run on the same machine as the clients, so any kind of IPC is ok
2. *sequential access*: `get next/previous key`
3. *two keys (string) per record*: kind of a bi-directional map, actually
4. *in-memory **only***: should have option for no persistence at all
5. RAM disk/tmpfs solution is not desirable
6. SQL/ODBC is an option, although not required
7. commercial product ok, if the OEM license price is reasonable

So far we have considered the following options, but no satisfactory solution yet:

- *mysql*: answers all requirements, but now answer yet as to how much an OEM license will cost
- *memcached, cassandra*: no sequential access, according to online docs
- *Redis*: seems as a nice tool, but again, I don't see get `get nex/prev` in the spec
- *Postgres*: couldn't make it work well on Linux/ODBC

Seems that all nosql in-memory DBs provide only direct access by key, hash-table style.
Have not checked Apache Derby yet.

We run on Linux, the client is in C++.

Will be glad to have your suggestions. Thanks!

**EDIT:** It seems that we will be pursuing the *mysql* option, we've got a reasonable price offer, and it will also be useful as our main (persistent) DB. Thanks for all answers, it is as usual difficult to select just one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [seeking recommendations for simple in-memory DB *server* (no persistence needed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246675/seeking-recommendations-for-simple-in-memory-db-server-no-persistence-needed) - prior question from same user

Comment: @Steve: I'd say it's a follow-up rather than a duplicate; the requirements are much more clearly formulated, and as a result, the answers are much more useful. Also, previously I was looking for SQL/ODBC DB, whereas here I am more interested in simpler nosql options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest Kyoto Cabinet, it has an in memory function and sequential access.

edit:
what's wrong with stl map?

Comment: 2) it is not a stand-alone server, and I don't want/have time to develop one

Comment: ok. Kyoto Cabinet can be treated as a stand-alone server using Kyoto Tycoon.

Comment: does it have memory-only (i.e. non-persistent) data?

Comment: it's just a network protocol over Kyoto Cabinet, so yes.

Comment: looks cool, thanks! It's GPL unfortunately. Do you know if they have a commercial license?

Comment: In that case have a look at Tokyo Tyrant, it's LGPL.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have a look at SQLite, with the database file name set to  ":memory:" this will create an in memory database that will no longer exist when your application closes.

It is public domain so that there is no issue with licensing

Comment: SQLite is an embedded DB, while I need a stand-alone server

Comment: @davka: Why? If it's running on the client's machine it's going to be no different whether it's embedded or not....

Comment: @Billy: because we have several processes that need this service. Even better reason, we have executables that run per each request (e.g. mail filters), so initializing such in-memory db for each run is expensive. So we need the data that is permanently in-memory (until the machine is restarted) and serves several clients

Comment: @davka: Interesting. +1 to the question then.

Comment: As your on linux, you could create a memory file system (tmpfs) and create a database there. this would then act as if it had the speed of the in memory database, as well as being shareable

Comment: to be in memory, it should be a ramdisk.

Answer (score 2):

[FastDB](http://www.garret.ru/fastdb.html) should work just fine. It supports in-memory configuration and shared access.

Answer (score 2):

Redis doesn't sort keys, but it does have lists/sets which allow you to retrieve items in order. It's hard to know for sure if that would work without knowing why you want sequential access, but with NoSQL you often need to think a little differently about the data structures you use.